# How to add CORS to .net core 3.2

Tags: c#, .net-core, cors, blazor, blazor-client-side

Since the new .net 3.2 preview no longer has a startup.cs with its ConfigureServices function, I am at a loss to figure out how to implement .AddCors.  The old way of adding services essentially was to add, then use a service.  It doesn't look like that's the way to do it anymore. What is the proper code to add CORS?

Program.cs

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using BlazorDemo.Shared;

namespace BlazorDemo
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);

            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDataLayer, DataLayer>();

            builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder
                    .AllowAnyOrigin());
            });

            builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

            await builder.Build().RunAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Data.cs

```
namespace BlazorDemo.Shared
{
    public class Data
    {
        public Country[] data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

DataLayer.cs

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace BlazorDemo.Shared
{
    public interface IDataLayer
    {
        Task<Country[]> FetchCountries(string sortField, bool sortDesc);
        Task<Country[]> FetchCountries();
    }

    public class DataLayer : IDataLayer
    {
        public DataLayer(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            this.httpClient = httpClient;
        }

        HttpClient httpClient;

        public async Task<Country[]> FetchCountries(string sortField, bool sortDesc)
        {
            var url = $"http://outlier.oliversturm.com:8080/countries?sort[0][selector]={sortField}&sort[0][desc]={sortDesc}&take=10";
            var data = await httpClient.GetJsonAsync<Data>(url);
            return data.data;
        }

        public async Task<Country[]> FetchCountries()
        {
            Country[] Countries;

            try
            {
                var url = $"http://outlier.oliversturm.com:8080/countries";
                var data = await httpClient.GetJsonAsync<Data>(url);
                Countries = ((Data)data).data;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Country c = new Country() { name = "DD", areaKM2 = 2, population = 50, _id = e.Message };
                Countries = new Country[] { c };
            }

            return Countries;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to add Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors NuGet then builder.Services.AddCors();

Comment: It's there already.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit lost now. Adding and configuring CORS is a server-side concern. Are you getting an error when calling http://outlier.oliversturm.com:8080 API?

Comment: How are you testing for CORS?  CORS is *implemented* by the browser, not the server, so the only thing you should be seeing if you are calling `httpClient.GetJsonAsync()` is a header.

Comment: Sorry I thought I responded to Mr. Hollerman.  The error I'm getting is "TypeError: Failed to fetch".  I'm expecting to get a json string "data: [... array of Country objects...].  You can check the url yourself.  No reason I shouldn't be able to get this except I'm not setting up CORS correctly.